# How to get attribute value of parent tag by passing child tag value in Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<category tid="titleId">
      <key>titlekey</key>
      <category-abbreviation/>
      <title>main title </title>
    </category>
```

For example, say for above document I need value of tid that is "titleId" and to fetch it I have input key=titlekey. Let me know how to find attribute value tid using xpath expression. documents can have multiple category nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath expression like this:
Locate the parent `category` node based on it's child element `key` value and then get the `tid` attribute value from that parent node.

```
"//category[./key[text()='titlekey']]/@tid"
```

You can also use this expression as well:

```
"//category[key='titlekey']/@tid"
```

Comment: Simpler and better is `//category[key='titlekey']/@tid`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelKay, I will add this solution as well